# Where is the right place to download monit for centos 6.2?

Tags: centos, monit

I have a centos 6.2 machine tried to yum install monit it says nothing to do. Then I have a link here http://pkgs.repoforge.org/monit/. Is this a reliable site or any other better suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: @MadHatter sorry for that now I have done most of it ready.

Comment: @mad now worries we work together and learn together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the [EPEL repository](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Comment: does it comes with monit in it? Is it stable enough based on your experience?

Comment: The EPEL repository is a de-facto repository for the extra packages not found in base RHEL/CentOS repositories. It's probably your best shot, as EPEL packages do not overlap with base repositories and do not cause dependency problems. Also, the software there is very stable -- typically not the bleeding-edge versions, but the well tested ones.

Comment: And yes, of course it contains Monit, otherwise I would not have mentioned it. :-)

Comment: I download the file I run this command rpm -i epel-release-6-6.noarch.rpm
warning: epel-release-6-6.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0608b895: NOKEY
There is a warning nokey is that something wrong here? Next I run yum intsall monit it works.

Comment: Totally legit. It just means you do not have the repo key in the rpm db yet (yum imports it the first time you use the repo). Of course, you should check the key matches the one published on the epel site.

Comment: @alien life I am keen to understand better this epel is a collection of tools for linux. How does it install when the .rpm file is so small how it works?

Comment: The repository rpm you downloaded contains only the information about EPEL repository itself. Then, every time you install something from the repo, the actual packages you want will be downloaded from the internet.

Comment: @JannePikkarainen how will yum know to pick from this repo and not the main centos repo? Any settings is done is it?

Answer (score 1):

http://repoforge.org/use/ Will tell you how to add the repoforge repo to your yum.
If, however, EPEL contains monit (I dunno) then it is more stable (in my experience) then repoforge.